signInAnonymously() not working and heartbeats undefined appearing
I used to use the www.gstatic/ to import the firebase but now that I migrated to electron I started using the local sdks instead. Currently when I start up the app I get seven duplicate console logs:
(7) C:\Users\budiy\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\Cornilieus\node_modules\@firebase\app\dist\index.cjs.js:1056 heartbeats undefined

renderer.js:788 Signing in

The message signing in comes from the following:
onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    if (user) {
        // do something
    } else {
        console.log("Signing in")
        signInAnonymously(auth).then((user) => {
            console.log(user);
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
        });
    }
});

Nothing of relevance appears after the logs in the console above, just the Electron Security Warning and key press detection detecting control shift i when I opened the dev tools
To anyone who knows the proper terms and usage feel free to edit my question
I have tried reverting to an older version of firebase, from 10.13 to 10.12.5, because this issue says that the heartbeats undefined logs stops when reverting the version. And as those messages seemingly appeared adjacently with the non functional functions I tried it. Neither of them happened and heartbeats undefined still appears in the console.
I also have deleted node_modules and reinstalled them because maybe it was a result of a messy install. Didn't work either

As per usual I find the answer after I post a question. That there is no solution + duplicate question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37327515/using-firebase-with-electron/47617348#47617348

I also have the same issue. hearbeats undefined keeps on popping up in the console.

Great do you know how to fix it
